Eigenvectors of block tridiagonal matrices
I need to know eigenvectors of a block tridiaognal matrix
$${\bf K} = T({\bf X},{\bf A},{\bf X}) =\begin{bmatrix}
{\bf A} & {\bf X} & {\bf O} & {\bf O} & \dots & {\bf O} & {\bf O} \\
{\bf X} & {\bf A} & {\bf X} & {\bf O} & \dots & {\bf O} & {\bf O} \\ 
{\bf O} & {\bf X} & {\bf A} & {\bf X} & \dots & {\bf O} & {\bf O} \\ 
{\bf O} & {\bf O} & {\bf X} & {\bf A} & \dots & {\bf O} & {\bf O} \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
{\bf O} & {\bf O} & {\bf O} & {\bf O} & \dots & {\bf A} & {\bf X}\\ 
{\bf O} & {\bf O} & {\bf O} & {\bf O} & \dots & {\bf X} & {\bf A}\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$
where ${\bf A}$ and ${\bf X}$ are $N\times N$ matrices. The eigenvalues of the matrix $T({\bf X},{\bf A},{\bf X})$ is the same as eigenvalues of the matrix
$$
{\bf A} + 2{\bf X}\cos\left(\frac{j\pi}{N+1}\right)
$$
where $j=1,2,\dots N$. This fact is described in Theorem 4.1 in the paper:
DOI: 10.1080/09720529.2020.1854939
(We can downlod it for free here)
My question is that, how can I find the eigenvectors of $T({\bf X},{\bf A},{\bf X})$?

I think that the first task is to find the eigenvectors of each of the $A+2\gamma_jX$, and if $v$ were one such then I'd look at $v\otimes f$ where $f$ is an eigenvector of the $N\times N$ matrix with $1$s on the super and subdiagonals and $0$ elsewhere.

I am not sure that you have quoted the referenced paper correctly, so let me change your notation a little.
Suppose that $A,X$ are $K\times K$ matrices, [sorry for the use of $K$ but that is what the referenced paper uses], and let
$$
T(X,A,X)=
\begin{bmatrix}
A & X & O & \dots &O&O\\
X & A & X &\dots & O&O\\
O & X & A &\dots & O&O\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots& \vdots&\vdots \\
O&O && \dots& A&X\\
O&O & &\dots& X&A
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where there are $N\times N$ blocks.
Define the $N\times N$ matrix
$$
J_N=
\begin{bmatrix}
0& 1 & 0 & \dots &0&0\\
1 & 0 & 1 &\dots & 0&0\\
0 & 1 & 0 &\dots & 0&0\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots&\vdots &\vdots \\
0&0 && \dots& 0&1\\
0&0 & &\dots& 1&0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
It is well-known (or easily checked) that the eigenvalues of $J_N$ are $2\cos\frac{j\pi}{N+1}$ for $j=1,2,\dots,N$. Let the corresponding eigenvectors be $e_1,\dots,e_N$.
Now let $\lambda_{j,1},\dots,\lambda_{j,K}$ be the eigenvalues of $A+2\cos(\frac{j\pi}{N+1})X$, and let $f_{j,1},\dots,f_{j,K}$ be the corresponding eigenvectors.
Now $T(X,A,X)=A\otimes I_N +X\otimes J_N$, and so we have
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
T(X,A,X)(f_{j,i}\otimes e_j) &=&
A f_{j,i}\otimes I_N e_j +Xf_{j,i}\otimes J_N e_j\\
&=&A f_{j,i}\otimes   e_j +Xf_{j,i}\otimes 2\cos\frac{j\pi}{N+1} e_j\\
&=&A f_{j,i}\otimes   e_j +2\cos(\frac{j\pi}{N+1}) Xf_{j,i}\otimes e_j\\
&=&(A + 2\cos(\frac{j\pi}{N+1}) X)f_{j,i}\otimes   e_j \\
&=&\lambda_{j,i}f_{j,i}\otimes   e_j \\
&=&\lambda_{j,i}(f_{j,i}\otimes   e_j). \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Thank you! I would like to confirm that the eigenvector $e_n$ can be written as
$e_n = [ \sin( \frac{n \pi}{N+1} ), \sin( \frac{2n \pi}{N+1} ), \dots, \sin( \frac{nN \pi}{N+1} ) ]^\top$, right?

I think that is right.
